# How to make a music bot join the voice call

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, pytube

So i have been seeing many youtube vids and got a working code
but I cannot find the error in my code

```py
import discord
from discord import Embed
from itertools import cycle
import os
import asyncio
import random
import json
import youtube_dl
import praw
from datetime import datetime as dt
from typing import Optional
from discord.ext import tasks,commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get
from keep_alive import keep_alive

def getprefix(bot,msg):
  return['d! ','d!','doge ','doge']


bot = commands.Bot(case_insensitive=True,command_prefix=getprefix)
bot.remove_command("help")

status = cycle(['Prefix=d!','Helping server','Prefix=doge'])

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('on')
  change_status.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_status():
  await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,activity=discord.Streaming(name=(next(status)), url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iik25wqIuFo'))

@bot.command(aliases=['j','enter','connect'])
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      em=discord.Embed(title="ERROR",description=f"{ctx.author.mention} You are not in a voice channel!")
      await ctx.send(embed=em)
    voice_channel=ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
      em=discord.Embed(description=f"Connected")
      await ctx.send(embed=em)
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
      em=discord.Embed(description=f"Reconnected")
      await ctx.send(embed=em)

@bot.command(aliases=['l','exit','leave'])
async def disconnect(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

@bot.command(aliases=['stop','halt','pau'])
async def pause(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    em=discord.Embed(description=f"Paused! {ctx.author.name}")
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@bot.command(aliases=['continue','res'])
async def resume(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    em=discord.Embed(description=f"Resumed! {ctx.author.name}")
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@bot.command(aliases=['run','display'])
async def play(ctx,url):
  ctx.voice_client.stop()
  FFMPEG_OPTIONS={'before_options':'-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5','options':'-vn'}
  YDL_OPTIONS={'format':'bestaudio'}
  vc=ctx.voice_client

  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    info=ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
    url2=info['formats'][0]['url']
    source=await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
    vc.play(source)
```

So if I am not in a voice channel the bot shows the error but when I am in the voice channel it doesn't join nor does it send any message.
So I cannot figure out my mistake and I really don't know if the rest will work as the first step itself has gone wrong.
Any help would be valuable

Comment: Please [edit] your question down to a [mcve], and include any errors you are getting (starting from the word *traceback*). This will help others better understand your question, and you'll get answers faster. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: okay i will look into it @TheFungusAmongUs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
if ctx.voice_client is None:
```

with

```
voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
if voice == None:
    await voice_channel.connect()
```

Alternatively:

```
 async def join(self, ctx):
        member = utils.find(lambda m: m.id == ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.members)
        if member is not None and member.voice is not None:
            vc = member.voice.channel
            await vc.connect()
            print('Joined a Channel')
```

Comment: It still doesn't join but this time it doesn't show any errors.
But I appreciate your efforts thank you

Comment: @ShwetaK I updated my post and made a new join command, which should definitely work (at least for me it did). If you want to print your errormessages you just need an additional else clause.

Comment: nope it did not join nor did it print that it joined @Ventior

Comment: is there any special scopes i have to add in the discord developer portal?
i gave it administrator perms but still

Comment: @ShwetaK huh, that really is weird. The only things I've activated is "Presence, Server Members and Message Content Intent" and of course invite the Bot as Administrator. 
I've even tried your code and replaced my join command with yours, with no problem whatsoever. There has to be some problem with the configuration of your bot otherwise I see no problem with it.

Comment: hey @ventior sooo i just updated to discord2.0 and it is working perfectly fine now ty for your help

Comment: @ShwetaK that's great to hear! Great that I could help!